# Best way to deploy nodejs code on docker, how to automatically install node_modules?

Tags: node.js, docker

Suppose the following simple nodejs docker starter:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    container_name: venko_node
    image: node
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '../src:/usr/src/app/'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    links:
      - mongo
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    command: node index.js
```

How can I make sure that node_module packages are installed in the first run?

I thougth of adding the command `npm install` before `node index.js` but it will try to install everytime I run. Is it a problem? What if I restart the server and it decides to update a bunch of packages?

Is there a better solution? If not, how can I put `npm install` before `node index.js`?

Comment: You need to build a custom image including your application; you can `RUN npm install` in your Dockerfile.  Do not use `volumes:` for your application code or your `node_modules` tree (the former leads to non-reproducible results; the latter prevents Docker from seeing updates to `package.json`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run `npm install` during image build (and not at the container start) you may want to create your own [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), it may looks like as follows:

```
FROM node

ADD . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

CMD node index.js
```

Then in the docker-compose configuration you need to define build [context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context) that is the directory where the `Dockerfile` is located. For example if the docker-compose config and the `Dockerfile` are in the same directory setting context to `.` should be work out:

```
version: '3'
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: '.'
    container_name: venko_node
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```